# Next.js middleware always return null as body

Tags: node.js, next.js, middleware, react-fullstack

Request has a body property, but it seems to always be null for me in middleware functions.

If reading the body is not supported in middleware it would be nice for the docs to note that, and maybe for NextRequest to throw a helpful error when the body is accessed. The current behavior is a bit confusing.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

const middleware = (req = NextRequest, ev) => {
  console.log("hey", req.body); // hey null
};

export default middleware;

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: "500kb",
      responseLimit: "3mb",
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where's the middleware located in your `pages` folder structure? What routes is the middleware on, and what POST request are you making?

Comment: in the api/v1/_middleware.js.  Its meant to apply to all routes in the v1 folder

Comment: Did you every find a solution @Chukwu3meka

Answer (score -1):

Now this seems to work

Just do `await res.json()`

Comment: Where does this `res` coming from?